# what is the right store?

Tags: isolatedstorage

im reading about isolated storage and im wondering:

when use GetMachineStoreForApplication 
         GetMachineStoreForAssembly
         GetMachineStoreForDomain
         GetUserStoreForApplication 
         GetUserStoreForAssembly
         GetUserStoreForDomain ?

do you have some samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **GetUserStoreForApplication** - You can use this isolated Store to share settings within the application

2) **GetUserStoreForSite** - You can use this isolated store to share settings within the application and between different applications on the same domain. You cannot share the settings if one application is running on localhost:4009 and an other application that is running on localhost:4010

Comment: GetUserStoreForSite  is supported only in Silverlight-based applications   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforsite(v=vs.110).aspx